# Translate encrypt SAS function to Power BI

Tags: sas, powerbi

I am doing this function in SAS (not created by me) to encrypt an id.
Is it possible to replicate it in Power BI?

```
put(sha256(compress(put(input(client_id, 10.),10.))||                                                     
            '3B9E336D986AFD0BD4E869869117B26DA9C2192A090878B6B9417C832DEDFAEE'
                                 ),$hex64.)
```

Thank you very much in advance.
Best regards

Comment: Can't do it in DAX or M/Power Query using the native functions, but there is a work outlined here in M/Power Query https://www.powerbi-pro.com/en/encrypting-values-in-power-bi/

Comment: Does POWERBI have the SHA256 function? Otherwise the remainder is fairly basic process that can be translated.

Comment: Don't know if sha256 function exists to be honest